# Keep colors when converting CMYK to sRGB to CMYK Imagick PHP

Tags: php, colors, imagick, color-profile

I'm trying to convert an original CMYK (Coated FOGRA27 (ISO 12647-2:2004) image to sRGB (Apple RGB) and later on back to CMYK (Coated FOGRA27 (ISO 12647-2:2004) and keep all colors as they were via Imagick in PHP. Now my knowledge of colors is not very high but I would like to get as close as possible to the original but after the conversion the color intensity seems quite off. I was was wondering if anyone knows a solution to keep the original colors.

For reference here are all original and converted images:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0_03DCODKMJVXRvRUhPQTh6ZjA?usp=sharing

I use the following code to convert the original image to sRGB (colors seem still fine after)

```
$img = new Imagick();

$img->readImage(  URL::to('/storage/' . 'images/7961_58d5017e0c3a6_2k_749/original/2k_749.jpeg') );

$img = Image::make( $img );

$img_core = $img->getCore();

$img_core->profileImage('icc', Storage::get('color_profiles/AppleRGB.icc'));

$img_core->transformimagecolorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);

Storage::put( 'images/7961_58d5017e0c3a6_2k_749/original/2k_749_rgb.jpeg', $img->stream('jpg', 100) );
```

I use the following code to convert the image back to CMYK

```
$img = new Imagick();

$img->readImage(  URL::to('/storage/' . 'images/7961_58d5017e0c3a6_2k_749/original/2k_749_rgb.jpeg') );

$img = Image::make( $img );

$img_core = $img->getCore();
$img_core->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$img_core->setImageResolution(300,300);

$img_core->profileImage('icc', Storage::get('color_profiles/CoatedFOGRA27.icc'));

$img_core->transformimagecolorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);

$return = Storage::put( 'images/7961_58d5017e0c3a6_2k_749/original/2k_749_conv.jpeg', $img->stream('jpg', 100) );
```

After this conversion the colors are are off, when using Photoshop to convert the sRGB version to CMYK the colors seem to be almost exacly the same, I was hoping this could also be achieved with Imagick in PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: I see the same issue when using ImageMagick on the command line - so I opened an issue upstream, to ask how best to preserve appearance. https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/426

Comment: btw using $imagick->setOption("black-point-compensation", $someValue); or the setRenderingIntent _might_ help here. However I have no idea what they actually are meant to be - if you find out let me know and I can add them to the Imagick manual and phpimagick.com